# BackgroundUploader throws COMException: ERROR_INTERNET_LOGIN_FAILURE

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I try to upload an image (choosen by FileOpenPicker) but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
var openpicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openpicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
openpicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
openpicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
var file = await openpicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

var uploader = new Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundUploader();

PasswordCredential pw = new PasswordCredential();
pw.Password = "mypw";
pw.UserName = "user";

uploader.ServerCredential = pw;

uploader.Method = "POST";
var uri = new Uri("ftp://myaddress/Directory/");

var str = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
await uploader.SetSourceStreamAsync(str);
uploader.SetRequestHeader("Filename", "image2.jpg");
var upload = uploader.CreateUpload(uri);

var result = (await upload.StartAsync()).GetResponseInformation().StatusCode;
```

I get the following exception in the last line:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80072EEF): Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EEF
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotificat‌​ion(Task task)

0x80072EEF   is ERROR_INTERNET_LOGIN_FAILURE:

> "The request to connect and log on to an FTP server failed."

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `await`ing the result of the *asynchronous* upload operation?

Comment: Yes. But the behavior is the same. It doesn't work.

Comment: What's the value of `(await upload.StartAsync()).GetResponseInformation().StatusCode`?

Comment: After adding your line code instead of upload.StartAsync() i get an exception: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EEF"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80072EEF): Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EEF\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

Comment: 0x80072EEF is ERROR_INTERNET_LOGIN_FAILURE. Double-check if you're using the right credentials and the URI is correct.

Comment: The provided credentials are definitely correct. I'm using the same credentials to logon via FTP application e.g. Filezilla

Comment: Check if any of the solutions provided [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/836941/en-us) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5274022/76217) helps.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work for me. Are the using of the URI correct? Can I use a "FTP" uri with BackgroundUploader? And should I set uploader.Method to "POST" or are there other Methods for FTP?

Comment: FTP servers are not created equal.  Try a url like `ftp://username:password@hostname`

Comment: Thanks for your replies. If I try "FTP://username:password@hostname:port/path" I'll get 
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
By await upload.StartAsync().
In my webbrowser "FTP://username:password@hostname:port/path" does it work.

Comment: have you find a solution for upload with ftp / sftp in windows metro app?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Even though this question is a bit old, I was directed here when searching for an answer.

i found that what is described [here](http://blog.thomaslebrun.net/2012/08/windows-8-how-to-download-files-from-ftp/#.UY0XqrVT4RY) got it working for me.
Basically BackgroundDownloader seems to fail when setting its ServerCredentials...

Comment: Better provide the details from the link, so that in future if the link will change then it would not impact.